# My External ip in AKS for deployed Nodejs api app not working

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, azure-aks, acr

I try to deploy simple nodejs API to AKS. API works fine in local docker. I get no errors. AKS that status is running. However browser does not respond. Could someone check yaml and give me some tips?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nodejs
  labels:
    app: nodejs
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nodejs
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nodejs
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
        - name: nodejs
          image: dileepamabulage/node-app:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3003
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nodejs
  labels:
    app: nodejs
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 3003
      protocol: TCP
```

my docker file used to build the docker image

```
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3003

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

When I try to access the external Ip it fails, are there any port mapping errors?

Comment: Ensure your Node.js application is configured correctly to listen on the correct port (3003). This is usually set in your application code (e.g., server.js). Do a kubectl get svc nodejs and verify the ext Ip, Ensure that there are no NSG rules or firewall blocking access to the external IP on port 80. Try port-forwarding to access your app internally within the cluster. This can help determine if the issue is internal or external: kubectl port-forward svc/nodejs 8080:80

Comment: Then access your app via http://localhost:8080. If this works, the issue might be with the LoadBalancer or external network configuration.

Comment: Check this document- https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-deploy-nodejs-apis-on-azure-aks-using-helm-8b37ab190d4e
 (https://i.imgur.com/ixyDmQX.png) (https://i.imgur.com/huLYWDO.png) You can refer to the deployment and service yaml inside the document.

Comment: @Arko is right. You need to ensure that your NodeJS app is listening on port 3003. Typically NodeJS apps listen on port 3000. In addition to the port-forward to the svc/nodejs you can port-forward directly to the pod to see if it responds on the port you configured (3003) by running kubectl port-forward nodejs 3003:3003 then try browsing to http://localhost:3003

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @arko for your insights, Here I have create a nodeJS application in my local and deployed it to my desktop docker using `Dockerfile`.

```yaml
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3003

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

[image]

- Then I have created ACR in azure portal and signed-IN using powershell CLI and pushed by docker image to acr container successfully.

[image]

Then created a `deployment.yaml` file and `service.yaml` file in my project directory and configured AKS configuration.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test023
  labels:
    app: test023
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test023
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test023
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
        - name: test023
          image: your-acr.azurecr.io/suresh/nodejs-app:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3003
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi



**service.yaml:**

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test023
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 3003
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: test023
```

**Status:**
[image]

[image]

[image]